# Install Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server on azure batch node

Tags: python, linux, azure, odbc, azure-batch

I am deploying Ubuntu Server 16.04 Canonical nodes to Azure Batch.
My Tasks need to access an Azure SQL server database and my code is written in Python.

Before I can use pyodbc, I need to install the Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server.

I've tried following the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server#microsoft-odbc-driver-13-for-sql-server) and added the commands to the Azure Batch Pool StartTask to install the libraries on the nodes, but I am getting errors...

Here are the commands executed by each node on start:

```
'sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y',
'curl -fSsL https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python',
'apt-get install -y python3-pip',
'pip3 install azure-storage==0.32.0',
'curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -',
'curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list',
'sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y',
'sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql=13.0.1.0-1 mssql-tools-14.0.2.0-1',
'sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev-utf16',
'ln -sfn /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd-13.0.1.0 /usr/bin/sqlcmd',
'ln -sfn /opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp-13.0.1.0 /usr/bin/bcp',
'pip3 install pyodbc'
```

The above commands (lines 5 to 11 are from the above link) are from the MS documentation...

The node StartTask fails with the following:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   983  100   983    0     0   4397      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4408
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100    79  100    79    0     0    753      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   759
E: Unable to locate package mssql-tools-14.0.2.0-1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'mssql-tools-14.0.2.0-1'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mssql-tools-14.0.2.0-1'
```

If you want to try this yourself, you can use the [following tutorial code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/Python/Batch/article_samples) and modify the `task_commands` in the `create_pool` function.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There probably is an issue with the name format of the package `mssql-tools-14.0.2.0-1`. Have you tried `mssql-tools=14.0.2.0-1` instead (note the equals)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below commands to install the ODBC driver and the pyodbc:

```
sudo apt-get -y update;
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive;
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip;
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils apt-transport-https;
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - ;
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list ;
sudo apt-get -y update ;
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install msodbcsql17 ;
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install mssql-tools ;
echo 'export PATH=\"$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin\"' >> ~/.bash_profile ;
echo 'export PATH=\"$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin\"' >> ~/.bashrc ;
source ~/.bashrc&& sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev ;
sudo pip3 install pyodbc;
```